# Session destroy is not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Session destroy is not working properly in codeigniter
header code

```
  if($session_data!="" AND $session_data['is_business_admin']=="1" AND  $session_data['is_system_admin']=="0" AND $session_data['is_super_admin']=="0" )
  {
       echo "business_admin is logout";
       echo "  Welcome <i>" . $session_data['first_name'] . "</i> !";   
  ?>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">      
   <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Admin/dashboard/'); ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Admin/logout/'); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                    </ul>
                         <?php   }
```

controller code

```
public function logout() {
// Destroy session data
$this->session->sess_destroy();

$data['message_display'] = 'Successfully Logout';
$message = "you are successfully logout";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
//$this->load->view('login', $data);
 $this -> login();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***In `__construct`***

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    ob_start(); # Add this
    $this->load->library('Session');
}
```

and in ***logout/session destroy*** part add this

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->cache->clean();
redirect(''); # your home controller
ob_clean();
```

Comment: Abdulla please tell me how I go to login page after logout using redirect

Comment: what is your loging controller name and method name??

Comment: our controller name is "Home" and we want to redirect to login method ( for display login page)

Comment: so use like this `redirect('home');`

Comment: No, it doesn't redirect login page

Comment: my login page is login.php

Comment: or send this to your home page

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('username_or_key_used_to_check_login');
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.